# Argument mismatch while using method reference

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, method-reference

The error is :

> EmpDemo.java:86: error: **no suitable method found for**
>   sort(ArrayList,EmpDemo::c[...]BySal)        Collections.sort(emp,
>   EmpDemo::compareBySal);
>                    ^
>       method Collections.sort(List) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
>           (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
>       method Collections.sort(List,Comparator) is not applicable
>         (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
>           (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
>             cannot find symbol
>               symbol:   method compareBySal(T#2,T#2)
>               location: class EmpDemo))   where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
>       T#1 extends Comparable declared in method sort(List)
>       T#2 extends Object declared in method sort(List,Comparator)
>   **1 error**

---

```
public class EmpDemo {

    int compareBySal(Employee e1,Employee e2) {
        return (int) (e1.getSal()-e2.getSal());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();

        //Adding employees
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
        {

            System.out.println("----Enter the  " +i +"TH Data------");
            System.out.println("Enter your salary");
            float sal=sc.nextFloat();

            Employee e=new Employee();
            e.setSal(sal);

            emp.add(e);
            System.out.println();

        }

        //displaying the employees
        System.out.println("Before Sorting.....");
        System.out.println(emp);

        //**Using METHOD REFERENCE**
        Collections.sort(emp, EmpDemo::compareBySal);

        System.out.println("Before Sorting.....");
        System.out.println(emp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `compareBySal()` method, simply sort like this:

```
Collections.sort(emp, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSal));
```

If `getSal()` returns a `float` (not obvious from your code), then the following version is even faster:

```
Collections.sort(emp, Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSal));
```

Comment: Or `emp.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSal));`. By the way, it seems that the property is a `float` value, so you would have to use `comparingDouble` in the specialized variant.

Answer (score 0):

Make `compareBySal` `static` in order for it to match the required functional interface:

```
static int compareBySal(Employee e1,Employee e2) 
{
    return (int) (e1.getSal()-e2.getSal());
}
```

or

```
static int compareBySal(Employee e1,Employee e2) 
{
    return Float.compare(e1.getSal(),e2.getSal());
}
```

In your original implementation, where `compareBySal` is an instance method, `EmpDemo::compareBySal` requires 3 arguments - an `EmpDemo` instance and two `Employee` instances. This doesn't match the `Comparator<Employee>` interface expected by `Collections.sort()`.

Another alternative (if you don't change `compareBySal` to be a `static` method) is to use a method reference of a specific instance:

```
Collections.sort(emp, new EmpDemo()::compareBySal);
```